# Angular 2 unit testing issues

Tags: unit-testing, angular, webpack, karma-jasmine

I am using angular rc.4 (unfortunately can't upgrade to newer version) and have some issues with unit testing.

My project was generated by [generator-ng2-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-ng2-webpack) and upgraded from rc.3 to rc.4.

Currently my simple test `expect(1).toEqual(1);` failures because of App injection, and I am getting strange error.

> _instantiateProvider@C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:23782:38
>    _new@C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:23771:42
>    getObjByKeyId@C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:23423:55
>    _getByKeyDefault@C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:23951:52
>    _getByKey@C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:23923:42
>    get@C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:23732:31
>    C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:34074:75
>    map@[native code]
>    execute@C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:34074:33
>    path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:34168:63
>    _instantiate@C:/path-to-project/karma-shim.ts:23908:98

Spec file

```
import {BaseRequestOptions, Http, Response, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend} from '@angular/http/testing';
import {provide} from "@angular/core";

class MockRouter {
  createUrlTree() {}
  navigateByUrl() {}
  navigate() {}
}

class MockActivatedRoute { }

// Load the implementations that should be tested
import {App} from './index';

describe('App', () => {
  // provide our implementations or mocks to the dependency injector
  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
      App,
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      { provide : Router, useClass: MockRouter},
      { provide : ActivatedRoute,  useClass: MockActivatedRoute },
      ...
    ]);
  });

  it('should have an url', inject([App], (app: App) => {
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  }));
});
```

karma.shim.ts (I made some changes as suggested [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/901#issuecomment-242894059))

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';

var appContext = require.context('./src', true, /root\.?spec\.ts/);

appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.setBaseTestProviders(
    browser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    browser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
);
```

my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.1.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-given": "^2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "karma-story-reporter": "^0.3.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-load-plugins": "^0.1.2"
    ...
  }
```

When i dont inject App

```
it('should have an url', inject([], () => {
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  }));
```

test works fine.

Also I need to test `App`s properties and website's routing, but cant find any guide how to do that on angular rc.4.

Comment: Also its possible to inject and test components